# app component's constructor and ngOnit methods are called twice in Angular 2

Tags: angular

```
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(){
       //block of statements
   }  
   ngOnInit(){

   }   
}
```

when i set debugger in constructor and in ngOnInit() then it comes twice in both the methods, I don't know how is happening

Comment: please add more details. How do you bootstrap your application? ... add your index.html and your main.ts

Comment: That's unusual. You need to provide more information for others to be able to diagnose the problem. How does `bootstrap()` look like? Can you reproduce in a Plunker (template https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)